# Событие мыши в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как описать событие, происходящее, когда мышь с зажатой левой кнопкой входит в элемент и там (над элементом) кнопка отпускается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полагаю, что Вы хотите реализовать drag and drop?
Если да, то я бы посоветовал так:
как только потащили элемент, записывать в глобальную переменную значение (объект или булевое значение). Тогда останется отслеживать только onmouseup, где проверять значение переменной и если там что то есть, то это перетаскивание.

В противном случае думаю придется вешать обработчики на три события:
onmousedown - записываем в переменную, что мы щелкнули уже внутри объекта и все последующие события игнорировать (тоесть мы не пришли извне с нажатой кнопкой, а уже здесь это сделали)
onmousemove - проверяем нажата ли наша кнопка (хотя этот метод можно пропустить). Он нужен, чтобы понять тащили ли над элементом или просто висели (использовать последние координаты над элементом).
onmouseup - если наша кнопка и переменная обработанная методом или не обработанная методом mousedown пустая, то нас тащили и отпустили.